# run curl in parallel from file using GNU parallel and save output into separate file with the name of the running job number

Tags: bash, shell, curl, grep, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run in parallel urls with curl, which are defined in one text file. Each url is on separate line. I need to call following grep command (`grep -Ev 'Server:\|Date:\|Content'`) on every output from curl and then every output I would like to save into separate file with the name of number of job that's currently running.

I'm using GNU parallel:

```
parallel --results  output/{#}.txt  -j+0 --k --eta g curl -XGET -I -s --max-time 5 < mytxt.txt
```

**input:**

mytxt.txt:

- url1
- url2
- url3
- url4
- url5

**output:** - every text file will contain output of curl with grep-ed information

```
1.txt

2.txt

3.txt

4.txt

5.txt
```

**Questions:**

1. `--result output/{#}.txt` generated also file ***.err** and ***.seq**, which I dont need. How could I generate only files like 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt... where the number is job number ?
2. I dont know how to use grep command with combination of parallel command (`grep -Ev 'Server:\|Date:\|Content'`), that will grep some information from every curl output.

Thanks for answer

Comment: It's not a comment. It's informing you of a rule and reason to close: **Needs more focus
This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy you give `--results` a try. `--results` is built for the more advanced case where you want to keep both standard out (STDOUT) and standard error (STDERR). In your case you can simply use normal redirection '>'.

If the command template is a composed command I prefer using a bash function. To me it makes it easier to get the quoting right. It has 2 additional benefits:

- I can easily test the function on a single value before giving it to GNU Parallel.
- It is easier to document each step of the function.

```
doit() {
  url="$1"
  output="$2"
  curl -XGET -I -s --max-time 5 "$url" |
    # We do not care about Server, Date and Content
    grep -Ev 'Server:\|Date:\|Content' > "$output"
}
export -f doit

parallel --eta doit {} {#}.txt < mytxt.txt
```

(-j+0 = default, so not needed)